# Can I use ale or syntastic as a pre-write hook instead of post-write?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I have a couple of YAML files that must contain valid YAML at all times, so I was hoping to use (something like) [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) or [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) to help me enforce that.

It looks like the way syntastic works is that after `:w` it runs the checkers (post-write) and reports any errors. Ale works asynchronously but doesn't prevent writes if there are errors. And they both work great as advertised.

But can I use the checkers to prevent the files getting written to disk with `:w` or `:wq` if they don't pass the checker(s) in a sort of pre-write hook fashion?

Or are there alternatives to ale and syntastic that allow that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer still would have to be persisted (e.g. to a temp file) for a checker to be able to inspect it. That's additional effort, and I'm not sure whether *Syntastic* has something like that.

For *ALE*, as it works asynchronously, it can do this easily. All that's left to do is preventing the write in case of errors. The errors can be obtained via [ale#statusline#Count()](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/blob/cae40e1c347064bd3ab5eb4c04e9e357d3d82105/doc/ale.txt#L2849-L2860); you just need to check that in [`BufWritePre`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufWritePre) and abort the write; this can be done by `:throw`ing an exception in the handler:

```
autocmd! BufWritePre <buffer> if ale#statusline#Count(bufnr('')).error > 0 | throw "You have errors in the file; fix them first." | endif
```

To apply this automatically to the "couple of YAML files", you can define a custom [`:command`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand) (e.g. `:EnforceNoErrors`) that lets you easily set up the `:autocmd` (preferably inside an `:augroup` then), or use another `:autocmd` to make this setting automatically:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /path/to/the/*.yaml autocmd! BufWritePre ...
```